# Pytorch cannot detect CUDA GPUs on GKE Autopilot Cluster with nvidia-tesla-t4 gpus

Tags: installation, pytorch, google-kubernetes-engine, autopilot

How to enable Pytorch to use GPUs on [GKE Autopilot cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/autopilot-gpus)?

I am using the `nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:21.10-py3` ([docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/pytorch-release-notes/rel_21-10.html)) image to run a container in a kubernetes pod with one nvidia-tesla-t4 GPU. GKE Autopilot manages driver installation ([docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/pytorch-release-notes/rel_21-10.html)).

Within the container, I run `nvidia-smi` and observe that there is a valid driver version (470.161.03), a valid CUDA Version (11.4), and a see that the Tesla T4 GPU is detected as device 0.

However, when I use try to run any script (or just use repl), `torch.cuda.is_available()` alwasy returns `False`. `torch.version.cuda` returns 11.4, and torch.__version__ returns 1.10.0a0+0aef44c.

Can one advise on how to debug?

The cuda versions match, and the gpu driver appears to be installed correctly. Why is pytorch unable to recognize cuda enabled gpus?

Comment: Any chance you can post a sample of your code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my job spec included a malformed value for the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable.